# Oracle Group By SQL not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the EMPLID, Z_SERV_DT_TYPE, and SERVICE_DT fields.  Most of the EMPLIDs have both a 'SAD' and 'TED' Z_SERV_DT_TYPE.  I want to group them all together and be able to see the SERVICE_DT field so it is easier to sort through the data.  When I run the below though it says, 'not a group by expression'  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
select EMPLID, Z_SERV_DT_TYPE, SERVICE_DT
from PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT 
where Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED', 'SAD')
GROUP BY EMPLID
```

Comment: Why do you use `group by`? As far as I can tell you simply want `order by emplid`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a group by to just list all the employees where type in TED and SAD

```
select EMPLID, Z_SERV_DT_TYPE, SERVICE_DT
from PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT 
where Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED', 'SAD')
order by Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
```

The select should have all columns that are in Group by

if you want to get count then you can use GROUP BY

```
select EMPLID, Z_SERV_DT_TYPE, COUNT(*)
from PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT 
where Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED', 'SAD')
group by EMPLID, Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max date, then you would need to use GROUP BY that includes all columns not using an aggregate function:

```
SELECT EMPLID
  ,Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
  ,MAX(SERVICE_DT) AS MAX_SERVICE_DT
FROM PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT
WHERE Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED','SAD')
GROUP BY EMPLID
  ,Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
```

That should give you the max date on a per `EMPLID` and `Z_SERV_DT_TYPE` combination. If you wanted the MAX date whether it was either type, then you could either remove the type:

```
SELECT EMPLID
  ,MAX(SERVICE_DT) AS MAX_SERVICE_DT
FROM PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT
WHERE Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED','SAD')
GROUP BY EMPLID
```

Or use a subquery:

```
SELECT EMPLID
  ,Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
  ,SERVICE_DT
FROM PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT
WHERE Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED','SAD')
    AND (EMPLID,SERVICE_DT) IN (
        SELECT EMPLID
          ,MAX(SERVICE_DT)
        FROM PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT
        WHERE Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED','SAD')
    )
```

Or if you wanted to get fancy, use an OLAP function:

```
SELECT EMPLID
  ,Z_SERV_DT_TYPE
  ,SERVICE_DT
FROM PS_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT
WHERE Z_SERV_DT_TYPE IN ('TED','SAD')
QUALIFY (
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY EMPLID
        ORDER BY SERVICE_DT DESC
    ) = 1
)
```

These are all on the fly so may require a little tweaking, but should give you an idea on how to approach it.